# Xml serialization c# enums only works on some computers

Tags: c#, xml, windows, serialization, enums

I have a problem with the xml serialization in c# for windows 7 64 bits.
I want to serialize the following class:

```
[XmlRoot("configuration")]
    public class ClaseQueSeSerializa
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Nombre")]
        public string Nombre { get; set; }

        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Edad")]
        public int Edad { get; set; }


        [XmlElement(ElementName = "tipoDeFichero", Type = typeof (Enumerados.teOrigenDato))]
        //[XmlIgnore]
        public Enumerados.teOrigenDato EnumeradoOrigen { get; set; }

        public ClaseQueSeSerializa()
        {
            Nombre = "John Connor";
            Edad = 15;
            EnumeradoOrigen = Enumerados.teOrigenDato.Fichero;
        }

    }
```

And this is the method that serializes:

```
public static class  Serializador
{

    public static object Deserializar(string file, Type type)
    {
        try
        {
            XmlSerializer xmlSerz = new XmlSerializer(type);

            using (StreamReader strReader = new StreamReader(file, Encoding.Default, true))
            {
                object obj = xmlSerz.Deserialize(strReader);
                return obj;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception(ex.Message);
        }
    }

    public static object Serializar(string file, Object obj)
    {
        try
        {

            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(obj.GetType());

            using (StreamWriter stream = new StreamWriter(file, false, Encoding.Default))
            {
                XmlSerializerNamespaces ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
                ns.Add(String.Empty, String.Empty);

                serializer.Serialize(stream, obj, ns);
            }

            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception(ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

This is the method call:

```
    if (File.Exists(RUTA_INSTALACION_CAM + @"\prueba.xml"))
        claseQueSeSerializa = (ClaseQueSeSerializa)Serializador.Deserializar(RUTA_INSTALACION_CAM + @"\prueba.xml", typeof(ClaseQueSeSerializa));
    else
        Serializador.Serializar(RUTA_INSTALACION_CAM + @"\prueba.xml", claseQueSeSerializa);
```

When I run it gives me the following error : error reflecting type NameProject.ErrorSerializarEnumerados
However when I run the generated exe  in other pcs, it works.

In addition, the code below serializes my class without errors in my comuter:

```
[XmlRoot("configuration")]
public class ClaseQueSeSerializa
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Nombre")]
    public string Nombre { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Edad")]
    public int Edad { get; set; }


    //[XmlElement(ElementName = "tipoDeFichero", Type = typeof (Enumerados.teOrigenDato))]
    [XmlIgnore]
    public Enumerados.teOrigenDato EnumeradoOrigen { get; set; }

    public ClaseQueSeSerializa()
    {
        Nombre = "John Connor";
        Edad = 15;
        EnumeradoOrigen = Enumerados.teOrigenDato.Fichero;
    }

}
```

So I think I have an error when serializing enums only in some windows 7 64 bits

All test PCs have installed windows 7 64bit.

I'm about to go crazy. Some genius knows what's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Change encoding From :  `Encoding.Default` To: `Encoding.UTF8`

Comment: I tried what you suggested, but it is not working. I think it does not solve the problem because when I ignore the enums, the class ClaseQueSeSerializa is being serialized correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I solve my problem updating .net framework 4.0 to 4.5.